# Phone's power and volume buttons will not work in bootloader

Tags: bootloader, troubleshooting

I have recently decided to unlock the bootloader of my BLU Studio X8 HD. I have first installed the ADB drivers and afterwards I have used the command
`adb reboot bootloader`
to boot the device into the bootloader. This was the only way to boot the device into the bootloader, PWD + Vol. UP goes to recovery, PWD + Vol. DOWN goes to factory mode (which contains a bunch of hardware-based tests), and PWD + Vol. UP + Vol. DOWN does nothing.

Afterwards, I ran
`fastboot oem unlock`
which displayed the `Are you sure that you want to unlock the bootloader on your phone?` screen on my phone. Vol. UP is yes and Vol. DOWN is no. I clicked both of the buttons and there was no response in the terminal or on my phone. I even pressed the PWD button after each time I pressed either of the volume keys.

I need help with unlocking the bootloader.